# http get from assets not work in published app

Tags: json, angular, typescript

In angular app I have assets/config.json file and I am want read file this while inialisiang app.

When run with ng serve locally I can access file with http://localhost:4200/assets/config.json

But when I hosted app in IIS on server, getting 404 error for URL
http://my-web-server/assets/config.json.

When run with ng serve locally I can access file with http://localhost:4200/assets/config.json

Comment: Please share the code you are using to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

simply don't use full path
just relative one: `../assets/config.json`

Comment: Tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

Add "assets/config.json" into your angular.json file into assets array under architect->build->options->assets

Comment: Entry already added , but still no luck

 "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/config.json",
              "src/appsettings.json"
            ],

Comment: @user1414709 Does file exist on the server? Is it wrong path or file not exists on server?